# PHP : How to properly use pathinfo after using base64 decode

Tags: php, arrays, pathinfo

I'm getting an error `Array to string conversion` at pathinfo after using base64 decode image.  Error occurs when trying to put my files into diretory. I need to maintain the name of the image.

BTW my image files came from js DOM

```
var formG = new FormData();
for(var i=0; i<imageTrust.length;i++){
    formG.append('file_multiImage[]', imageTrust[i]);
}


if(isset($_POST['file_multiImage'])){
    $multi_image =  $_POST['file_multiImage'];
    foreach ($multi_image as $key => $value) {
        $staticName = $event_id.'conNo'.$finalContestantNum;
        $data = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $value);
        $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $file = pathinfo( $staticName . PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Error occurs here
        file_put_contents($theDir.'/'. $file, $data);

    }
}
```

The array result

```
Array(
       [0] => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA 
       [1] => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAlgCWAAD
       [2] => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QC
)
//I did not just continue strings are too long
```

Comment: First you had better [read the manual for file upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) as you have made quite a few basic mistakes processing the $_FILES array or rather NOT processing the $_FILES array

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think my question is incomplete my images are came from dom (data:image) then i decode it base64

Comment: your `pathinfo()` has a full stop instead of a comma separating the function arguments.

Comment: In that case can you add the output from a `print_r($_POST);` to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax issue that the parser wouldn't have detected.

`$file = pathinfo( $staticName . PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

change to

`$file = pathinfo( $staticName , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

however, your next usage of `$file` seems invalid, creating a malformed filename for the `file_put_contents()` call. By specifying `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` you are picking just the extension from
 the filename, which doesn't appear to exist.